# Setting up Breezejs with Entity Framework 6

Tags: angularjs, breeze, entity-framework-6

I hope that someone can help me out here.  I have just started working with angularjs and breezejs. I am coming from a more traditional MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6 background with this.

I have been working through the Breezejs documentation, in particular how to get the meta data configuration working, but I have to say this is where the documentation is vague. The grammar used refer to 'we', and this is where I (English is my 3rd language), struggle. Do they mean, we the developer working with it in the end, or we the breezejs team.  Confusion sets in when I simply cannot find a working example of this either.

So far I have created an empty web application, and installed the nuget packages for breezejs ef, angularjs and hot towel. I also created a separate efmodel project and created code from database. This is now where I get stuck.

Can someone please point me to an example, or help me out how to get it wired up so that my breezejs uses my ef6 model meta data.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in regards to the words that they use - they are referring to the author of the document and the read together as 'we' meaning that when they say we need to add a metadata endpoint on the WebAPI controller or something that you need to do it and follow along with how they are suggesting.

As far as samples of using Angular with EntityFramework 6 and Breeze just go to their samples site which has a plethora of sample solutions that should point you in the right direction.

http://www.breezejs.com/samples

Good luck!